# libKF5Parts SO Undefined Symbol Arch

Tags: arch-linux, libraries, qt

When starting programs such as `Okulus` and `Dolphin` I get the following error:

> symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libKF5Parts.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN3KIO18CommandLauncherJobC1ERK7QStringRK11QStringListP7QObject

Googling this suggested it may be a `QT5` installation issue so I've reinstalled `qt5-base` and `qt5`.

Looking in `/usr/lib` for this file, I can see the library and its symlinks with what appear to be the correct permissions.

> james@dev-box  ~    ls -la /usr/lib/*KF5Par*
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 May  3 10:07 /usr/lib/libKF5Parts.so -> libKF5Parts.so.5
>
> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 May  3 10:07 /usr/lib/libKF5Parts.so.5 -> libKF5Parts.so.5.70.0
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 476944 May  3 10:07 /usr/lib/libKF5Parts.so.5.70.0

What else can I look at to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: nope, I've still got the issue

Comment: I did a full upgrade by issuing `pacman -Syu` and the issue is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had to modify the PKGBUILD of the packages solid-git and kcodecs-git, on the line 'source', I replaced "git://" by "git+https://"

I use yay, I did :

```
➜  ~ yay --editmenu -S solid-git
:: Vérification des conflits...
:: Vérification des conflits internes...
[Aur: 1]  solid-git-v4.100.0.rc1.r389.g8dfb727-1

  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> Paquets à nettoyer avant compilation (cleanBuild) ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==>
:: PKGBUILD à jour -- omission (1/1) : solid-git
  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> Afficher les diffs ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==>
:: (1/1) Lecture de SRCINFO : solid-git
  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> PKGBUILDs à modifier ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> ^C
➜  ~ yay --editmenu -S solid-git
:: Vérification des conflits...
:: Vérification des conflits internes...
[Aur: 1]  solid-git-v4.100.0.rc1.r389.g8dfb727-1

  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> Paquets à nettoyer avant compilation (cleanBuild) ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> A
:: Suppression (1/1) : /home/clement/.cache/yay/solid-git
:: Téléchargement des PKGBUILD (1/1) : solid-git
  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> Afficher les diffs ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> N
:: (1/1) Lecture de SRCINFO : solid-git
  1 solid-git                        (Installé) (Fichiers de compilation existants)
==> PKGBUILDs à modifier ?
==> [N]Aucun [A]Tous [Ab]Annuler [I]nstallés [No]nInstallés ou (1 2 3, 1-3, ^4)
==> 1
```

And modify the line source :

```
source=('git://anongit.kde.org/solid.git')
```

by :

```
source=('git+https://anongit.kde.org/solid.git')
```

Quit the editor, and it should works.

I did it again with the kcodecs-git package

Right now, it should be OK for the solid-git package because I edit it, but we need to wait for the maintainer of the package kcodecs-git, or you can do it manually as explained.